# How to copy blob (binary data) from one DB to DB using a script?

Tags: sql-server, blob

We are trying to copy a `blob` (binary data) from one Database to another Database using a simple script. This is the steps we do.

1. Select the value using MSSQL Studio Client.
2. Copy it into the clipboard.
3. Paste it into an`INSERT` script using `notepad`.
4. Apply it into the destination database.

We notice that the value is now an `ASCII` that starts with `0x255....` which seems to be the `hexadecimal` representation of the `binary` data. Is there a way we can convert it back to binary during the insert?

Is there a better way to copy `blob` data using scripts? Assume, we don't have direct connection to destination Database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use the "Generate Scripts" option in SQL Server Management Studio.

1. In Object Explorer - highlight the database hosting the source
   table.
2. Right-click menu - Tasks | Generate Scripts
3. Select specific table object - click Next page
4. Click Advanced button
5. Under General Options
       - Change ***'Type of data to script'*** to **"*Data Only*"**
6. Save to file - change folder and filename as required.

I tried a simple test with a table storing a `varbinary` field.  The output from the Scripting process looked ok:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tjc_blob]    Script Date: 07/04/2017 14:46:23 ******/
INSERT [dbo].[tjc_blob] ([id], [datablob])
VALUES (1, 0x6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A)
```

Comment: You, sir, are my savior. Thank you.